# Really basic AJAX

Tags: php, ajax

I'm just starting out with AJAX. I'm trying to create a test where I enter some text into a text input box, click a submit button on a form, and have that text display on my page. The immediate error that I am getting is a 404 error ( www.mysite.com/ajaxFunction() ), but I'm sure that there are others yet to be discovered. Can anyone please help me correct this to get me started out with AJAX? I'm spinning my wheels trying to get started. Also, please realize that I am calling a php script since this is what my ultimate goal will require, which is why I'm not just using JavaScript itself. Thanks!

Here is the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html
PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    <!-- 
    //Browser Support Code
        window.onload = function ajaxFunction() {
            document.myform.action = getFeedback();
        }

        function getFeedback() {
            var xmlhttp;
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else {  
                // code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() { 
                if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
                    document.getElementById("feedback").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            }
            xmlhttp.open("GET","scripts/handle_feedback.php",true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
    //-->
    </script>

    <div id="leftsidebox"></div>

    <div id="textboxdiv">
        <form name="myform">
            Text Here: <input type="text" name="textbox" id="name" />
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div id="feedback">
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

handle_feedback.php

```
<?php
    $mytext = $_REQUEST['textbox'];
    return $mytext;
?>
```

EDIT: Here is my latest html code. I made the change to the php (switching 'return' to 'echo')

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
<!-- 
//Browser Support Code
    window.onload = function ajaxFunction() {
        document.myform.onsubmit = getFeedback;
    }

    function getFeedback() {
        var xmlhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {  
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() { 
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
                document.getElementById("feedback").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        var textvalue = document.getElementById("name").value;
        xmlhttp.open("GET","scripts/handle_feedback.php?textbox="+textbox,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
//-->
</script>

<div id="textboxdiv">
    <form name="myform">
        Text Here: <input type="text" name="textbox" id="name" />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>

<div id="feedback">
</div>
```

scripts/handle_feedback.php

```
<?php
    $mytext = $_REQUEST['textbox'];
    echo $mytext;
?>
```

Comment: For a start, `echo` instead of `return` the response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This won't do what you're expecting it to do:

```
document.myform.action = getFeedback();
```

You're probably expecting it to make it call `getFeedback` when the form is submitted. That's not actually what happens. When the browser tries to run that code, it will realize: “oh, hey, we're assigning `action`. But wait, on the right hand side, there's a function call! I've got to evaluate that function call in order to find the return value to set `action` to!” And so your browser dutifully calls `getFeedback` immediately. Since `getFeedback` doesn't return anything, it sets `action` to `undefined`. Boy, that was helpful.

If we want a JavaScript function to be called when the form is submitted, setting `action` is not the right way to do it. So what is the right way? *An event listener.* The most common way of attaching an event listener is using `addEventListener`, but since your use case is rather simple, we're going to use a simpler, often neglected way: setting `onsubmit`:

```
document.myform.onsubmit = getFeedback;
```

Note that we **do not** have parentheses after `getFeedback`. This is intentional. We want to set `onsubmit` to the `getFeedback` function itself, not its return value.

---

You're also using `textbox` without defining it. Sure, it exists in the document, but that doesn't mean it's a variable available in the script. To access it, you'll need to first get the element and then get that element's value:

```
document.getElementById('name').value
```

---

Another thing that might be getting you is the same origin policy. Rather than using a complete URL to `open`, just pass a relative URL:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", "something.php" /* ... */, true);
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the explanation. It makes sense. So I changed that line, but I'm still getting the same result (after also making the changes suggested by Yogesh. No more 404 error, but also no output on my original page.

Comment: Each time I hit Submit, I see an error flash momentarily but then disappears. Looks like it says "Uncaught ReferenceError: textbox is not defined". Sure looks like it's defined to me, so I must be missing something.

Comment: Yes, I realized that from one of the other posts. I changed that (code edited above). Now no console errors, but STILL no output. ARRGH! Thanks a ton for your help. I really appreciate it. Can you see what I am doing wrong? I'm thinking it might be on the php side that it's not returning anything. Just a guess, but it would explain why my page still shows no output.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't change anything. I don't get how something so simple can be such a mess.

Comment: @usr55410: Perhaps set a break point on the `if` statement of your `onreadystatechange` with your browser's JavaScript debugger and see if anything unexpected happens.

Comment: Good call. (didn't even know i could do that, btw). It looks like it is never evaluating that if statement to true and thereby never executing the innerHTML statement. Any ideas why??? Looks like this might be the key to the dilemma. Thanks for that tip!

Comment: @usr55410: Look at the local variables to see what condition is evaluating to false. That may hint at whatever is causing the problem.

Comment: It's the status. It always is 0. I've been trying to figure out why, but I'm stumped. Checking the local variables, I see that 'status' reports a DOMException but I see no further information it. I'm using Chrome. No idea how to handle this. The Google isn't giving me anything helpful.

Comment: Scratch that. I found something that suggested to change the async to false for this debugging purpose. The DOMException just arose because it hadn't been set yet. I stepped through the function line-by-line. I can see the div being set to my text value as the last line of execution - just as I would hope. But then, one more step to "execute" the last curly bracket and it disappears. What??? How can this be?

Comment: We've gotten so far away from the original intent of this post that I'm going to make a new post to focus on this specific issue. Thanks a ton for all of your help. I couldn't have gotten this far without you. I'm going to mark your post as the answer since it really did resolve my original question.

Answer (score 2):

It should be `echo` not `return`. `return` is used in function to return the data.

```
<?php
$mytext = $_REQUEST['textbox'];
echo $mytext;
?>
```

Also you have to send the parameter to php file

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","scripts/handle_feedback.php?textbox=your_value",true);
```

Comment: Thank you. I've made both of these changes. I'm still getting the 404 error, so I must not be calling the function properly. Also, how do I get the actual value into that line of code (rather than the literal string "your_value").

Comment: @usr55410 Are you sure the path to the php file proper? Its the php file path error.

Comment: Yes. The URL in the browser says "www.xxxxx.com/ajaxFunction()" so it looks to me like its not even getting to the php file.

Comment: @usr55410 I am saying about this url `scripts/handle_feedback.php?textbox=your_value`. Check it I am sure its not proper.

Comment: I changed that line to write out the entire path: "http : // www.xxxxx.com/scripts/handle_feedback.php?textbox="+textbox   Note the change at the end also. Now, my URL says the "www.xxxxx.com/ajaxtest.html?textbox=whateverientered"  I verified that the php script is on the server. But I still don't get any output on my original page.

Comment: @usr55410 refer __icktoofay's__ answer, he has described it in detail.

Answer (score 1):

First point : you missed request parameters from client end.

Send parameters in querystring for GET request.

```
var textvalue = document.getElementById("name").value;
xmlhttp.open("GET","scripts/handle_feedback.php?textbox="+textvalue ,true);
```

for more reference [read here](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp).

And second point is :

'**return**' statement is used with functions/methods. Since you don't have any function here, so instead of that use '**echo**' or '**print**' statement.

```
<?php
$mytext = $_REQUEST['textbox'];
echo $mytext;
?>
```

Comment: Thanks. I made that change. No errors now, but still no output to my page.

Comment: Check if you are getting value of textbox in javascript.